# How can one download several PDFs from Overleaf at once?

Tags: pdf, overleaf

I wonder how I can download several PDFs from Overleaf at once (1 PDF for each project, the PDF corresponds to the compiled version of the project). Sometimes I'd like to export a few PDFs to read later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there is not a way to do this: you need to compile the projects individually to produce the corresponding PDFs, then download them. Sorry for the limitation.

The best way to ask Overleaf support questions is to send an email to support@overleaf.com or use the contact link: overleaf.com/contact. We're happy to answer questions like this (I'm a member of the support team at Overleaf).

Answer (score 0):

There is still no way to download several PDFs from Overleaf at once, however it is now possible to download a PDF directly from the list of all overleaf projects:

[image]